# C++11 unique_ptr array and constructor parameters

Tags: c++11, stl, smart-pointers

I have a C++ class called Widget and I can use C++11 smart pointer array facility to create a dynamic array of them as follows:

```
std::unique_ptr<Widget[]> widget(new Widget[number_of_widgets]);
```

Now, I have changed the object so that the constructor now takes two integer parameters. Is it still possible to use a smart pointer array and call the parameterised constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can but only if you know the exact number of element you're building at compile time:

```
const std::size_t number_of_widgets = 2;
std::unique_ptr<Widget[]> widget(new Widget[number_of_widgets]{Widget(1, 2), Widget(3, 4)});
```

*[Live demo](http://ideone.com/bUcOJo)*

Otherwise you can't.

However, usually using smart pointer for array is not a good design, especially with `unique_ptr` where a simple `vector` (or `array`, or `string`) would do the same job in the end.

Quoting Scott Meyers:

> The existence of `std::unique_ptr` for arrays should be of only intellectual interest to you, because `std::array`, `std::vector`, and `std::string` are virtually always better data structure choices than raw arrays.

Comment: Thank you for that. I guess I can use std::array with a similar initialisation list idea.

Comment: Good quote from Scott Meyers. However sometimes I like to use raw arrays with smart-pointers (I don't know why!).

Comment: This [breaks on clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9adda0f3719c068f). OTOH, https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=22924

Comment: I disagree with Scott Meyers, sometimes you need have direct control over lifetime of array. Its happen when you need send or receive array from some library (that can be written in C). Aside form that, prefer `std::vector`.

Comment: @Yankes, with unique ptr, only one guy can own the array at a time, but with a `vector` that's also true. In both case you can move it. In both case you can decide to "kill" it (`reset` or `clear`) in addition to normal object life time. Am I missing something that `unique_ptr` has but `vector` hasn't?

Comment: You can't release responsibility of memory to someone else completely. With `std::vector` there is always some vector that own this data. Can you send this data to C interface that will be release by it? No, you can't because vector still own this data. `std::unique_ptr` can forget that is own any thing, vector do not.

Comment: @Yankes that's a very small corner case because you'll also have to deal with new/free incompatibility.

Comment: @Hiura and this is why `std::unique_ptr` can have custom deallocator. And I disagree that is small corner case. It could be main point of your library if you want have portable API (using C as bridge).

Answer (score 2):

Actually the question is independent of smart pointers, it amounts to
*"how to initialize the `new Widget[number_of_widgets]`"* using a constructor with parameters.

The answer is: you can't.